# FFmpeg Dual Fisheye to Equirectangular Conversion - Dark Shadow

Tags: ffmpeg

Why when I use FFmpeg conversion of 360 photos I always have a dark shadow on them along the stitch edges.

I tried the Remap command method described by Paul Bourke which is supplied online and used the V360 command. Each method produces the dark shadow. When I use the camera manufacturer's Stitching app the dark shadow does not appear.

The conversion is from dual fisheye side by side to equirectangular. I tried cleaning the dual fisheye images by replacing the black background with colour white, and I removed the outer edge of the dual fisheye images to remove any possible corruption but the dark shadow does not disappear.
I then assumed the shadow was lens vignetting. I then used FFmpeg Vignette command with no success. See image below where A=0.1.

After cropping the Font image and the Rear image which are attached, I examined closely and determined the shadow is likely the result of reflected light off the lens metal bezel ring into the lens.

[image: Rear Image]
[image: Front Image Yaw 180]
[image: Vignette Applied A=0.1]
[image: Output Highlighting Shadow]
[image: Input]

This is link to full sized images.
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/n9tzav9xpws404dlaxd1j/h?dl=0&rlkey=jvo3lvihi4ihyotkuxmn0h5yj

Comment: Not 100% certain that the light reflected off the lens metal bezel ring is the source of the dark shadow along the stitch edge. I will look into creating a transparent overlay to blend White into the problem area. I have tested this potential solution with GIMP by spraying White on transparent layer over the areas with limited success.